# Missing predictor variable in GLMM.nb outcome

Tags: interaction, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution, main-effects

After running the model:

```
    mod16.5 = glmer.nb(Richness ~ (0 + Buffer + Area_MN_Woody + Area_MN_Herbaceous + 
    PD_Herbaceous + LPI_Woody)^3 + (1 | Classification/Site),  data = dat_3)
```

I get the outcome

```
    Buffer1km                                      ***
    Buffer200m                                     ***
    Buffer2km                                      ***
    Buffer500m                                     ***
    Area_MN_Woody                                  ***
    Area_MN_Herbaceous                             ***
    PD_Herbaceous                                  ***
    LPI_Woody                                      *  
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Woody                          
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Woody                        ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Woody                          
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Herbaceous                  ***
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Herbaceous                   ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Herbaceous                  ** 
    Buffer200m:PD_Herbaceous                       ***
    Buffer2km:PD_Herbaceous                           
    Buffer500m:PD_Herbaceous                       ***
    Buffer200m:LPI_Woody                           ** 
    Buffer2km:LPI_Woody                               
    Buffer500m:LPI_Woody                           ** 
    Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous                  
    Area_MN_Woody:PD_Herbaceous                       
    Area_MN_Woody:LPI_Woody                        ** 
    Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous               ***
    Area_MN_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody                   ***
    PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody                        ***
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous    ***
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous     *  
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous    ***
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Woody:PD_Herbaceous         ***
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Woody:PD_Herbaceous          ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Woody:PD_Herbaceous         ***
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Woody:LPI_Woody             ** 
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Woody:LPI_Woody              ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Woody:LPI_Woody                
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous    *  
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous     ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous       
    Buffer200m:Area_MN_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody        ***
    Buffer2km:Area_MN_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody         ***
    Buffer500m:Area_MN_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody        ***
    Buffer200m:PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody             ***
    Buffer2km:PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody              *  
    Buffer500m:PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody             ***
    Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous ***
    Area_MN_Woody:Area_MN_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody        
    Area_MN_Woody:PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody          *  
    Area_MN_Herbaceous:PD_Herbaceous:LPI_Woody
```

I see that 1km was noted as significant in the main effect, however I don't see it in the 2-way or 3-way interaction. What happened to it?

I included the "0" in code because I first noticed the 1km was not taken into account since it was the first value listed in the 'Buffer' column.

Thank you

Comment: This is a FAQ about coding categorical variables: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+code+interaction+missing.